# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object not found

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to edit a column of a `data.table` by running through values of another column in the same `data.table`. However, when I do this, I get the following error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found`. Below I've made a simple case of where this happens in my own code.

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) 
x = list(n, s, b, 3, c(n,s), b, 5)

DT <-  data.table(grp=c("a","a","b","b","b","c","c"), foo=1:7, bar=x, y=rep("", length(x)))

for (i in 1:nrow(DT)) {
  if (DT[grp[i]=="a"]) {
    DT[,y[i]:= c(x[[i]], x[[5]][i]]
  }
}
```

However, clearly `y` exists, as I can simply type `DT[,y]`, or even `DT[,y[7]]`. Why is this happening?

EDIT: The actual code is a fair bit more complicated than this example here; the reason I feel stuck using a for loop is because, based on the result of the `if` statement, I then use a `while` statement to run along values of `x[i+n]`, adding all of the relevant `x[i]` to `y[i]`, until the stop condition is met. I thus feel that the iterative element is important.

Comment: Don't you mean simply `DT[,y:= x]` ?

Comment: Ahh, you were definitely right for the earlier example, which was definitely too simple. I've made it a bit more representative of the actual problem.

Comment: (there are more reasons why that doesn't work, but mainly) there is no column called `y[i]`; you're thinking atomically and need to start thinking in vector space

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I understand that, while it's almost certainly a bad idea to do so, is  there any way to edit individual rows of `y` in a similar manner? In my actual code, based on the result of the `if` statement, I then run through the next elements of `x[i]` using a `while` loop, adding all `x[i]` to `y` until the condition of the while statement is met.

Comment: @mlinegar yes, and that way is pointed out in the answer below (2nd line of code); you might also want to use the `set` function in for-loop-land; fyi a lot of the time new R users think that they have to use a for loop, while in reality they're just not utilizing vectorized options - might not be the case for you, but keep it in mind

Comment: Please go through the [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) as well, if you've not already.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to replace the entire `y` column in the data.table, use

```
DT[ , y:= x ]
```

If you want to replace the a subset of the `y` column, indicate the subset in the first "slot" of the [,] operator:

```
DT[ i, y := x ]
```

This can be done with logical tests, such as

```
DT[ grp=="a", y := bar ]
```

This won't reproduce exactly your question, but I believe it's easy to adapt it from here. If it's not, please drop a comment.

Using the subset instead of the loop has a much better performance, and is much more idiomatic for R.

Edit: you can see a **LOT** of examples, use cases and differences between := and [<- syntax on the man page for `` ?`:=` ``

Comment: EDIT: the comment I was replying to got deleted. 

Anyway, it would be better if the OP gave some details on what the data used actually mean. But the general idea of subsetting by the first slot in [ , ] and changing the column in the second is definitevely better than using a for loop and checking a condition.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt my code to use subsetting, but given the complexity of the for loop - I put in a new comment above detailing this a little better - it would really be very nice if it were possible to continue using the for loop, at least for the time being. Running through `x`, though definitely much slower then subsetting, seems to be a better option for capturing `x[i+n]` additional observations and putting them all into `y[i]`. 

I'm very sorry to keep changing the frame of the question, thank you so much for your help and patience.

Comment: Hm. You *can* use the `for` loop and `DT[ i , y:= etc ]`, but the code will become more complicated. If performance is not an issue, you might revert to data.frame, and simply use `DT[i, j] <- whatever you want`. If performance is an issue, you might want to implement this code in C++, and reference it with Rcpp

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you mean by reverting to a data.frame? I still get the same error as in the OP by typing `DT[i,y] <- "a"`. If you mean to convert the DT to a DF, might I ask how to fit a list into a column of a DF?

Comment: By "reverting to a data.frame", I mean rewriting the code using only data.frames, and no data.tables. They are waaaay less optimized, but their interface is much more intuitive.